# Saving the state of a SurfaceView when the Activity is stopped and resumed

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity with a SurfaceView that is managed by a game engine (thread).  I'm overriding the onCreate and the onSaveInstanceState for managing the save/restore state of the thread.

When the preferences screen is accessed from the menu of that Activity, that Activity goes through its lifecycle to onStop; when the preferences screen is closed, the Activity starts again at onResume, so onCreate does not happen.  The thread however is in a state of TERMINATED and therefore cannot be resumed.

Yes, I can just create a new instance of the thread--but how can I restore the state?  I tried overriding onRestoreInstanceState as well, but after a quick test and reading a little more thoroughly I realized that it's not called in this situation because it's called between onStart and onResume.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the dirty design of my app.  Since the game engine itself is extending the Thread class and automatically being set to `TERMINATED`, my only option with the current design is to add logic to the `surfaceCreated` method.  In there, I can check the state of the thread:

If it's `TERMINATED`, I can create a `Bundle` and pass it to my engine's saveState method.  Once I have the state, I make the thread a new game engine thread and pass in the recently saved `Bundle`.  I think continue as normal (start the thread).

This works, but the best way would be to move the actual Thread logic to a separate class.  Since the game engine isn't actually being cleared, I would just be creating a new `Thread` instance instead of recreating the entire game engine, so this is what I'll do.

Comment: You didn't mention about game engine in your question! your question is a general problem but you solved it in a special situation.

Comment: The issue here was with threading, not the game engine implementation; the solution I proposed in this case was to not inherit from `Thread` when implementing any game engine implementation that is managing state.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do need to target the `onSaveInstanceState` and either `onRestoreInstanceState` or use the `onCreate` functionality to do it (`onRestoreInstanceState` is called after `onStart`, whereas `onCreate` is called before `onStart` - so you'll need to use the `onCreate` way of doing things, although I'll list both below)

Save your state in the `onSaveInstanceState` of your activity - you may need to write getter methods in to your surfaceView class:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  outState.putInt(YourSurfaceViewClass.SOME_ID, surfaceViewClass.getVar());
  super.onSaveInstanceState(saveBundle);
}
```

And restore the values in `onCreate`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  if (savedInstanceState != null){
    value = savedInstanceState.getInt(YourSurfaceViewClass.SOME_ID);
  }
}
```

or `restoreInstanceState`:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    value = savedInstanceState.getInt(YourSurfaceViewClass.SOME_ID);
}
```

These methods will be called when you access the preferences screen and then use `onCreate` to restore your thread's state.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I've already tried this, as I mentioned in my post.  onCreate is not getting called in this case, and neither is onRestoreInstanceState [since it goes straight to onResume].